# how do you execute multiple `kubectl` commands for multiple clusters in parallel?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, parallel-processing, kubectl

i have an application that takes a long time because it operates on multiple clusters.

for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for kube_context in a b c d e f; do
    kubectl config use-context ${kube_context}
    kubectl get pods
done
```

normally to speed this up i would just use multiple processes via something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
pids=()
for kube_context in a b c d e f; do
    (
    kubectl config use-context ${kube_context}
    kubectl get pods
    ) &
    pid=$!
    pids+=( $pid )
done
for pid in ${pids[@]}; do
    if wait ${pid}; then
        echo "DEBUG: pid=$pid: success"
    else
        exitcode=$?
        echo "WARNING: pid=${pid}: failure (exitcode=${exitcode})" >&2
    fi
done
```

but i can not use multiple processes because they are all using the same Kubernetes config file.

## how do you execute multiple `kubectl` commands for multiple clusters in parallel?

p.s. Does `kubectl` have a `--context` similar to `--namespace`, yes/no? If no, what is the best current practice?

p.p.s. i think this question may be similar to what is seen here: https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/issues/12

Comment: `kubectl` has a `--context` flag. For example: `kubectl --context prod-cluster get pods` to get pods in the `prod-cluster` context.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl` does not support running multiple commands in parallel. You would have to do this on the shell level.

There is a `--context` flag which you can use. There is no need to modify the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable or to run `kubectl config use-context`.

I modified your script a bit, but haven't tested it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
pids=()
for kube_context in a b c d e f; do
    (
    kubectl --context "${kube_context}" get pods
    ) &
    pid=$!
    pids+=( $pid )
done
for pid in ${pids[@]}; do
    if wait ${pid}; then
        echo "DEBUG: pid=$pid: success"
    else
        exitcode=$?
        echo "WARNING: pid=${pid}: failure (exitcode=${exitcode})" >&2
    fi
done
```

Comment: lol i should have checked for `--context` first. doh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using `kubectl config use-context ${kube_context}` in backgroud `&` is a good idea.

`kubectl config use-context ${kube_context}` modifies the kubeconfig file, which indicated a potential race problem.

I recommend that preparing independent kubeconfig for each cluster, instead of using context.

```
for example, we have 3 clusters:

~/kubeconfig_dir/clsuter_1
~/kubeconfig_dir/cluster_2
~/kubeconfig_dir/cluster_3

if we have multiple user/role: readonly/ admin/ clsuter-admin, we can organize as below:
~/kubeconfig_dir/cluster_1_dir/readonly
~/kubeconfig_dir/cluster_1_dir/admin
~/kubeconfig_dir/cluster_2_dir/admin

etc.
```

then you can do a complicated operation with kubectl as below:

```bash
# this is a scirpt

# you can get this from cli argument
export KUBECONFIG=~/kubeconfig_dir/cluster_3

# it's safe to do combiantion operations
kubectl get po -o wide | grep critical-pod;
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  kubectl get cm --namespace=kube-system critical-config -o json;
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

### idea #1: 3 lines of custom Bash code at the start of the new process to set env var `KUBECONFIG`

- have each new process copy the Kubernetes config file to a temporary file
- set up a `trap` to automatically clean up the temporary file
- set the value of the env var KUBECONFIG to the temporary file path
- do `kubectl config use-context ${kube_context}`
- do the necessary cluster commands (in the above example that would be `kubectl get pods`)

### idea #2: use a new tool called `kubech`

- from the link https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/issues/12 there is reference to a new tool called `kubech` located here https://github.com/aabouzaid/kubech
- looks like `kubech` might do what is needed
- but i have not tried it out yet